# What is the difference between “INSERT IGNORE” and “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

What is the difference between INSERT IGNORE and INSERT…ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. I would also like to know which one is preferred over the other. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to avoid duplication violation, then the difference is: `INSERT IGNORE` does not allow to specify an action (to alter something in a row) if unique constraint violation occures whereas for `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` some action specifying is compulsory. Of course, you can specify fake update in `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (for example, `SET id=id`, where `id` is primary/unique key) - in this case there is no difference.

`INSERT IGNORE` also may ignore some another ignorable errors, rather than `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.